# После запуска не открывается Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Когда запуская eclipse появится workspace,выбираю проект после загрузки не открывается eclipse,но он стоит в диспетчер задаче.если снова открою и выбираю тот проект то появится сообщение 'please choose another workspace[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2cUP.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у вас случайно другой эклипс не висит?

Comment: нет это тот эклипс который я открыл и не запускался

Comment: @bekzhan-ab пробовали полностью удалить `eclipse` и установить заново?